# How to convert a QuadTree Cell's Spatial Index (Binary Index) to Position and Dimension values?

Tags: actionscript-3, indexing, logical-operators, quadtree

Sorry in advance for miss-using any terminology in this question, but basically I'm looking into creating a QuadTree that makes use of Binary Indexing, like this:

[image]  [image]

As you can see in the two illustrations above, if each cells are given a binary ID (ex: 1010, 1011) then every **ODD** binary indices controls the X offset and every **EVEN** binary indices controls the Y offset.

For example, in the case of the **Level 2** grid (16 cells), *1010* (cell #10) could be said to have 1s at it's *4th* and *2nd* index, therefore those would perform two Y offsets. The first '1###' (on the leftmost side) would indicate an offset of one cell-height, then the second '##1#' would additionally offset it twice the cell height.

As in:

```
// If Cell Height = 64pixels
  1### = 64 pixels
+ ##1# = 128 pixels
__________________
  1#1# = 192 pixels
```

The same can be applied to the X axis, only it uses the odd numbers instead (ex: #1#1).

Now, when I initialize my QuadTree, I began calculating the maximum nodes it may contain if all cells and all depths are used. I have calculated this with the **sum of 4 to the power of each depths**:

```
_totalNodes =   0;

var t:int=0, tLen:int=_maxLevels;
for (; t<tLen; t++) {
    _totalNodes += Math.pow(4, t); //Adds 1, 4, 16, 64, 256, etc...
}
```

Then, I create another loop (iterating from **0 to _totalNodes**) which instantiates the nodes and stores it in a long array. It passes the current iteration integer to the Node *constructor*, and it stores it as it's **index**.

So far I've been able to determine which depth (aka: Level) the Node would be stored in by figuring out it's index's **Most Significant Bit**:

```
public static function MSB( pValue:uint ):int {
    var bits:int =      0;

    while ( pValue >>= 1) {
        bits++;
    }

    return bits;
}
```

But now, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to convert the index from binary form to actual Cell X and Y positions. like I said above, the dimensions of each cells are found. It's just a matter of doing some logical operations on the whole index (or "bit-code" is the name I refer to in my code)

If you know of a good example that uses logical-operations (binary level) to convert the binary index values to X and Y positions, could you please post a link or explanation here?

Thanks!

---

Here's a reference where I got this idea from (**note**: different programming language):

**L. Spiro Engine - http://lspiroengine.com/?p=530**

I'm not familiar with the language used in that article though, so I can't really follow it and convert it easily to ActionScript 3.0.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I've been over-complicating things with the way my cells are arranged in memory. I went with a more linear approach (from top left to bottom right, iterating horizontally first) and now I've got a working QuadTree that can identify the node based on a query Rectangle! :) The challenge will be querying the Quadtree and getting the parent nodes and child-nodes.

Comment: Just to keep a history going, I managed to get this working with each nodes indexed linearly. Here's a quick demo: http://pierrechamberlain.ca/demo.php?demo=Pierre_FastTree_test&folder=others

Answer (score 1):

your task is described by Hannan Samet. 
This works by first building the quadtree, and then assign to each quad cell the coresponding morton code. (bit interleaving code).
once you have the code, you assign it to the objects in the quad. then you can delte the quad tree. you then can search by converting a coordinate to the coresponding morton code, and do a bin search on the morton index. Instead of morton (also called z order) you als can use hilbert or gray codes.